# how to kendo modal move option window

Tags: kendo-ui, draggable

When I click the button, 
the kendo popup pops up, and I want to know the option to move the popup in the browser.
draggable: {
  containment: "#editor-form"
},

The draggable option does not move it.

```js
$("#add").on("click", function(){
  
   var start = new Date();
   start.setSeconds(0);
   start.setMinutes(start.getMinutes()+5);
   
   var end =  new Date ( start ); 
   start.setSeconds(0);
   end.setMinutes(start.getMinutes() + 30 );
    
   var event = {
    scheduleId: 0,
                title: "",
                start: start,
                end: end
    } ;
   
   editEvent( event );
}); 

function editEvent( event ){
  currentEvent = new kendo.data.ObservableObject(event);   
  kendo.bind(editor, currentEvent); //Bind the editor container (uses MVVM)
  editor.data("kendoDialog").open();


}
```

:
                :

Answer (score 0):

In such case I would rather use Window Kendo widget that is draggable by default - https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/window/index.